# Oracle result without group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm running below query on Oracle Exadata.

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic
>   Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing
>   options

```
select sum (t.sum_edw_trx_cnt) 
  from ( 
         select max(x.edw_trx_cnt)sum_edw_trx_cnt, 
                x.prctr_cell_nbr
           from p_prctr_smpl_pf_sp3 x
          where  mdld_prctr_flg = 'Y'
       )t;
```

I was expecting oracle to return an error since - As you can see there's no `group by` clause in the inner query “t” and I was expecting this query to fail.

There are millions of records and for each `prctr_cell_nbr` I want max count and then outer query should sum up max counts for every `prctr_cell`.
It's a simple query.
However, query runs and returns the output of `112` which is max count from the inner query.

I'm puzzled by this behavior since this is not the correct result returned by query. I don't think this is a known behavior, has anyone seen this recently ?

Thanks

Comment: You do however get an error if you just run the inner select correct?

Comment: Yes. Inner query results into error if run separately.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39674/why-is-a-non-single-group-group-function-allowed-in-a-subselect-but-not-on-it

Comment: Does it yield the proper results?  If so: I must give props to the engineers who worked with the DBEngine compiler then.  The system is smart enough to recognize that the x.prctr_cell_nbr and missing group by MAKE NO DIFFERENCE.  other than to define a max value for each set of records. the system is able to do this but since it doesn't need to display the values of x.prctr_cell_nbr, the system simply ignores the value.  However, if it's not giving the correct results, then a bug this be. It likely has something to do with order of operations.

Answer (score 8):

What you see is the effect of applying "select list pruning" by the optimizer. In this case it is considered to be a bug -  if an in-line view contains an aggregate function, unreferenced column(s) in the main query, and there is no `group by` clause, optimizer decides to simply get rid of those unreferenced columns(SLP - select list pruning):

Environment: Windows x64; Oracle 12.1.0.1.0

```
-- test-table 
create table t1 as
  select level as col1
       , level as col2
    from dual
  connect by level <= 7;

-- gather statistic on t1 table. 
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('', 'T1');
```

Now let's execute that buggy query with 10053 trace enabled and see what will happen under the cover:

```
alter session set tracefile_identifier='no_group_by';

alter session set events '10053 trace name context forever';

select /*+ qb_name(outer) */ col1
  from (
         select /*+ qb_name(inner) */ max(col1) as col1
              , col2
           from t1
       );


      COL1
----------
         7 

alter session set events '10053 trace name context off';
```

There was no expected `ORA-00937` error. Everything went smoothly. Now the trace file:

```
OPTIMIZER INFORMATION

******************************************
----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=d14y7zuxvvfbw) -----
select /*+ qb_name(outer)  */ col1
  from (
         select /*+ qb_name(inner)*/max(col1) as col1
              , col2
           from t1
       )
*******************************************
.....

Query transformations (QT)
**************************
....
SVM: SVM bypassed: Single grp set fct (aggr) without group by.

/* That's where we lose our COL2 */

SLP: Removed select list item COL2 from query block INNER
query block OUTER (#0) unchanged

....

Final query after transformations:******* UNPARSED QUERY IS *******
SELECT /*+ QB_NAME ("OUTER") */ "from$_subquery$_001"."COL1" "COL1" 
  FROM  (SELECT /*+ QB_NAME ("INNER") */ MAX("T1"."COL1") "COL1" 
           FROM "HR"."T1" "T1") "from$_subquery$_001"
```

As a workaround the `_query_rewrite_vop_cleanup` parameter can be set to `false`. But of course consult with oracle support if this parameter needs to be set in a production environment.

```
alter session set "_query_rewrite_vop_cleanup"=false;
session altered

select /*+ qb_name(outer)  */ col1
  from (
         select /*+ qb_name(inner) */ max(col1) as col1
              , col2
           from t1
       );
```

Result:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

And when we add `group by` clause, the query works as expected.

```
select /*+ qb_name(outer) */ col1
  from (
         select /*+ qb_name(inner) */ max(col1) as col1
              , col2
           from t1
          group by col2
       );
```

Result:

```
COL1
----------
         1 
         6 
         2 
         4 
         5 
         3 
         7
```

If you have access to MOS, take a look at [1589317.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=17137722185027&id=1589317.1&displayIndex=11&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=13q79ssqhl_298#FIX), [16989676.8](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=576941298744414&id=16989676.8&displayIndex=10&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=17tnb17ah8_441)(Bug 16989676 - should be fixed in 12.1.0.2 release), [Bug 8945586](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=17143777600666&id=8945586.8&displayIndex=12&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=13q79ssqhl_335) notes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply. I tried with  : alter session set "_query_rewrite_vop_cleanup"=false; and Oracle throws error as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the results could be correct if group by clause is excluded.
The result by outer query would be correct only when the inner query produces 
single record which is same as exclusion of group by column.

```
-- No group by clasue and Oracle silently ignores group by in
-- inner query and retrns the max numbre. See output showing count = 1

select sum (t.sum_edw_trx_cnt) ,count(1) from (
 select max(x.edw_trx_cnt)sum_edw_trx_cnt, x.prctr_cell_nbr
 from p_prctr_smpl_pf_sp3 x
 where  x.mdld_prctr_flg = 'Y'
 )t;

SUM(T.SUM_EDW_TRX_CNT)  COUNT(1)
----------------------------------
112                     1
`

-- Here is the query with group by clause 
-- The number of cells are indicated by count and the sum of edw_trx_cnt is 
-- 19838749 as expected.
`       
select sum (t.sum_edw_trx_cnt) ,count(1) from (
 select max(x.edw_trx_cnt)sum_edw_trx_cnt, x.prctr_cell_nbr
 from p_prctr_smpl_pf_sp3 x
 where  x.mdld_prctr_flg = 'Y'
 group by x.prctr_cell_nbr 
 )t;`

SUM(T.SUM_EDW_TRX_CNT) COUNT(1)  
----------------------------------
19838749               14106326
```